# Why is GitHub Actions trying to use SSH?

Tags: github, ssh, github-actions

I have a release workflow in GitHub Actions which first checks out with `actions/checkout@v3`, then uses `changesets/action@v1` to publish packages in a monorepo to npm.

According to the [changesets action source code](https://github.com/changesets/action/blob/main/src/index.ts#L27), it tries to set the user with `git config user.name`, and email, and then creates a `.netrc` file [here](https://github.com/changesets/action/blob/main/src/index.ts#L31) as:

```
machine github.com
login github-actions[bot]
password ${githubToken}
```

`git reset --hard`, and `git checkout` works fine, but when it comes to pushing:

```
| [command]/usr/bin/git push origin HEAD:changeset-release/main --force
| git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
| fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
| 
| Please make sure you have the correct access rights
| and the repository exists.
```

it seems like it's trying to use It to `push`.

As far as I know `actions/checkout@v3` uses HTTP to authenticate, so complaining about `publickey` seems off as it indicates that SSH is being used for authentication.

Any ideas?

I tried to manually replicate the issue, and ran the workflow locally using `act`, using an all rights PAT.

Comment: You could ask in an issue on that action?